# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal attempt to set ViewHandler after a response has been rendered

Tags: jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, jsf-2, glassfish, richfaces

My Java EE web application is working fine with Glassfish 2.1. Now I want to migrate to Glassfish 3.1.1, but after a successful deployment of the war file it gives following error:

```
WARNING: ApplicationDispatcher[/Myapp] PWC1231: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal attempt to set ViewHandler after a response has been rendered.
```

My application uses following frameworks.

- Spring Framework 3.0.2
- JSF 2.0
- RichFaces 3.3.3 Final

It's compiled with JDK 1.6.

How is this problem caused and how can I solve it?

**EDIT**

I have followed the modifications provided [here](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/RichFaces333AndJSF20)

my dependencies for richfaces are as follow:-

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.richfaces.framework</groupId>
        <artifactId>richfaces-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.richfaces.framework</groupId>
        <artifactId>richfaces-impl-jsf2</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.richfaces.ui</groupId>
        <artifactId>richfaces-ui</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

my jsf dependencies are

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId> 
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId> 
            <version>2.0.2</version> 
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId> 
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId> 
            <version>2.0.2</version> 
        </dependency>
```

added context param in web.xml as follow:-

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.ajax4jsf.VIEW_HANDLERS</param-name>
    <param-value>com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DISABLE_FACELET_JSF_VIEWHANDLER</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

modified my application descriptor with version 2.5 like:

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
```

my  in faces-config is as follow:-

```
 <application>
        <navigation-handler >
            org.navigation.CustomNavigationHandler
        </navigation-handler>

        <view-handler>
            org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler
        </view-handler>
<!--        <view-handler>
            com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler
        </view-handler>-->
        <variable-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.DelegatingVariableResolver</variable-resolver>
        <message-bundle>MyMessages</message-bundle>
    </application>
```

Application get deployed successfully but after that i am getting error of class cast exception at the time starting an application in browser :

server log is as follow:

```
INFO: myApp was successfully deployed in 21,635 milliseconds.
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/login.xhtml]
javax.faces.FacesException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to javax.faces.component.UIComponent
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.createComponentApplyAnnotations(ApplicationImpl.java:1923)
```

how can i resolve this??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal attempt to set ViewHandler after a response has been rendered.

This is a typical error message when you use a JSF 1.2 targeted component library on a JSF 2.x environment. RichFaces 3.3.x is designed for JSF 1.2, but Glassfish 3.1 ships with JSF 2.1 instead of JSF 1.2 as in Glassfish 2.1. In JSF 2 there are quite a lot of changes in the area of view handling, because JSP has been deprecated and replaced by Facelets.

RichFaces has an excellent guide how to install and configure RichFaces 3.3.3 in a JSF 2 environment: [RichFaces 3.3.3 and JSF 2.0](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/RichFaces333AndJSF20). The key step to solve this particular exception is adding the following context parameter which disables the JSF 2 Facelets view handler:

```
<context-param>
     <param-name>javax.faces.DISABLE_FACELET_JSF_VIEWHANDLER</param-name>
     <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

But more steps needs to be done as well. Read the guide thoroughly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. i have followed the instructions but still i am getting an error can you please see the edit?

Comment: That's a different problem. This can occur when you incorrectly used `binding` attribute instead of the `value` attribute of a component to bind the value to a backing bean. Please ask a separate question for a different exception.

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove the  Ajax4jsf library from my application before I could get this error to go away.  Evidently, the  Ajax4jsf library is not compatible with JSF 2.0.

Here where I found this.
[Migrating JSF 1.1 with Ajax4jsf-1.x to JSF2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17553033/migrating-jsf-1-1-with-ajax4jsf-1-x-to-jsf-2)