# JSF2.0 + Richfaces + Facelet is correct?

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, tomcat6, facelets

I create simple project using the following environment.
1. Netbeans IDE6.9.1  (File->NewProject->Select JSF2.0 libraries)

1. Tomcat 6.0.29

jars
1.Commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
2.commons-collections-3.2.jar
3.commons-digester-1.8.jar
4.commns-logging-1.0.4.jar
5.el-funstions.jar
6.jhighlight.jar
7.cssparser-0.9.5.jar
8.guava-r09.jar
9.sac-1.3.jar
10.richfaces-api-3.3.3.Final.jar
11.richfaces-impl-3.3.3.Final.jar

```
12.richfaces-ui-3.3.3Final.jar
13.jsf-facelets-1.1.15.B1.jar
14.JSF 2.0-jsf-api.jar
15.JSF2.0-jsf-impl.jar
16.JSTL 1.1-Standard.jar
17.JSTL 1.1- jstl.jar
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Production</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<!--Configuration for Richfaces-->

<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.SKIN</param-name>
    <param-value>blueSky</param-value>
</context-param>


<filter>
    <display-name>RichFaces Filter</display-name>
    <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.ajax4jsf.Filter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
<!--End of the configuration part for Richfaces-->

 <!--Configuration for Facelets-->
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.jsp</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.RECREATE_VALUE_EXPRESSION_ON_BUILD_BEFORE_RESTORE</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.VIEW_MAPPINGS</param-name>
    <param-value>*.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<!--End of the configuration part for Facelets-->

 <!-- The following attribute facelet    -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DISABLE_FACELET_JSF_VIEWHANDLER</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<!-- End of The following attribute facelet    -->
</web-app>
```

faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config version="2.0"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd">
<application>
    <view-handler>com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler</view-handler>
</application>
</faces-config>
```

index.xhtml file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding="UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W#C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
     xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
     xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
     xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">
<h:body>
             Hello Facelet
             <h:outputText value="Sample output text"/>
             <rich:panel>
                   <f:facet name="header">
                          <h:outputText value="Sample Panel"/>
                    </f:facet>

                     <h:outputText value="Panel content added here"/>
              </rich:panel>
<h:body>
</html>
```

When i run my project, i got the following error. 
and also i don't know the above configuration and jars are correct ot not.

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Illegal attempt to set ViewHandler after a response has been rendered.
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)
org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)
org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal attempt to set ViewHandler after a response has been rendered.
com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.setViewHandler(ApplicationImpl.java:562)
org.ajax4jsf.event.InitPhaseListener.beforePhase(InitPhaseListener.java:92)
 com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.handleBeforePhase(Phase.java:228)
 com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:99)
 com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116)
 com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
 javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
 org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)
 org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
 org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
 org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
```

Help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you're choosing the old RichFaces 3.3.x which is designed for JSF 1.2, instead of RichFaces 4.x which is designed for JSF 2.x? Is there also any particular reason that you're choosing the old Tomcat 6.0.x instead of 7.0.x? In any way, check this similar question which I by coincidence answered shortly ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8831281/java-lang-illegalstateexception-illegal-attempt-to-set-viewhandler-after-a-resp

Comment: No reason for selected Richfaces3.3.3,  I want implement JSF2.0 + Richfaces4.0.0 + Tomcat 6.x.

Comment: Oh, why do you have RF 3.3.3 libraries then? This exception won't occur if you use RF 4.x instead of 3.x. Left only one question, why Tomcat 6 instead of 7?

Comment: Thanks baluC, just i am updating my project JSF1.2 to JSF2.0. Not update richfaces libraries. Later i will update RF4.x. Here i acheive need myhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863014/jsf2-0-richfaces-3-3-3-jsp-not-found-error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the view handler setting in *faces-config.xml* to

```
<application>
  <view-handler>org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler</view-handler>
</application>
```