# JSF2.0 + Richfaces 3.3.3, jsp not found error

Tags: tomcat, jsf-2, richfaces, netbeans-6.9

I created simple project using JSF2.0 + Richfaces3.3.3 + tomcat6.0.29 in Netbeans6.9.1

Step1 : File -> NewProject + Select JSF 2.0 + Prefered Page Language as **JSP**

Step 2: Jar

```
JSF2.0 jsf-api.jar
JSF2.0 jsf-impl.jar
JSTL1.1 - Standard.jar
JSTL1.1 - jstl.jar
jsf-facelets.jar (Facelets 1. 1. 15)
richfaces-api-3.3.3.Final.jar
richfaces-ui-3.3.3.Final.jar
richfaces-impl-jsf2-3.3. 3.Final.jar
commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar
commons-collections-3.2. 1.jar
commons-digester-2.0.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar and hth-api-0.4.0.jar
```

web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Production</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DISABLE_FACELET_JSF_VIEWHANDLER</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

 <context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.SKIN</param-name>
    <param-value>blueSky</param-value>
</context-param>


<!--Configuration for Richfaces-->
<filter>
    <display-name>RichFaces Filter</display-name>
    <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.ajax4jsf.Filter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
<!--End of the configuration part for Richfaces-->

<!--Configuration for Facelets-->
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.jsp</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.RECREATE_VALUE_EXPRESSION_ON_BUILD_BEFORE_RESTORE</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.VIEW_MAPPINGS</param-name>
    <param-value>*.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<!--End of the configuration part for Facelets-->


<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/welcomeJSF.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

and faces-config.xml file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config version="2.0"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd">

 <managed-bean>
    <description>Managed Bean for HomeContent</description>
    <managed-bean-name>Sample1</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.test.Sample1</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>

</faces-config>
```

welcomeJSF.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://richfaces.org/a4j" prefix="a4j"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://richfaces.org/rich" prefix="rich"%>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<f:view>
 <html>
<head>   
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
    <body>
      <h:form id="sampleForm" binding="#{Sample1.initForm}">               

        <a4j:outputPanel id="sampleOutputPanel">

          <h:outputText value="UserName : "/>
          <h:inputText value="#{Sample1.username}"/>

          <a4j:commandButton value="Test" 
                             reRender="sampleOutputPanel,output"
                             action="#{Sample1.displayButtonAction}"/>

         <h:outputText id="output" 
         value="Typed username : #{Sample1.displayValue}"/>
    </a4j:outputPanel>
</rich:panel>
</h:form></body> </html></f:view>
```

and Sample1.java

```
package com.test;
import javax.faces.component.html.HtmlForm;

public class Sample1 {

    private HtmlForm initForm;
    private String username;
    private String displayValue;

    public String displayButtonAction() {
        displayValue = username;
        return "";
    }


    public HtmlForm getInitForm() {
        username = "";
        return initForm;
    }


    public void setInitForm(HtmlForm initForm) {
        this.initForm = initForm;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getDisplayValue() {
        return displayValue;
    }

    public void setDisplayValue(String displayValue) {
        this.displayValue = displayValue;
    }
}
```

**MY problem is :**

After deploy my war into my tomcat6.0.29, run my application.
When i click the a4j:commandbutton the following error occur

```
HTTP Status 404 - /.jsp not found
type Status report
message /.jsp not found
description The requested resource (/.jsp not found) is not available.
Apache Tomcat/6.0.29
```

Help me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of your action is used to find the new view to display. Either by finding a match for it in faces-config or if there is no mapping there by using it directly as the name of the page. As you return an empty string you end up with only .jsp as the filename. If you want to go back to the same page return null instead of an empty string.

Comment: Hi Eelke, Thanks for response. Its worked for me. I didn't return 'null' value for a4j action in JSF1.2. Why JSF2.0 need return null value for a4j:action. Hele me.

Comment: It was added in 2.0 that the outcome can directly name a view. So the handling of the outcome is slightly changed.

Comment: Thanks Eelke. Thanks for your explanation. And one more doubt, I am new one for (JSF 2.0 + Richfaces3.3.3). In my above configurations (web.xml, faces-config.xml) are correct??? or otherwise any thing i miss it???

Answer (score 1):

Return null in displayButtonAction method

```
public String displayButtonAction() {
    displayValue = username;         
    return null;     
}
```

OR rewrite your action method with return type void

```
public void displayButtonAction() {
        displayValue = username;         

    }
```

Comment: Hi Naveen, Thanks for response. Its worked for me. But in existing JSF1.2 application, i didn't return 'null' value for any a4j action. Is there any reason for returning 'null' in JSF2.0 for a4j action

Comment: Implict navigation is introduced from JSF2.0, it treats “outcome” as the page name, for example, navigate to “page1.xhtml”, you have to put the “outcome” as “page1″. However JSF1.2 doesnot have implict navigation but used to navigate by finding a match (outcome) in faces-config.xml. Looks like return "" was handeled as null in JSF 1.2 but not in JSF2.0

Comment: Ok..thanks Naveen. I am new one JSF2.0 + richfaces3.3.3. In my above configurations are correct or not??? otherwise any other configuration miss???