# JSF1.2 to JSF2.0 Migration issue

Tags: jsf-2, migration, jsf-1.2

In my sample application working JSF1.2, richfaces3.3.1 and Tomcat.
Run my application in **chrome**:
My first page  URL  like http://localhost:8080/sampleapp/login.jsp and
after login my page like http://localhost:8080/sampleapp/faces/content.jsp.

Just i copy the url and paste to **FireFox** and then browser shows load the 
URL Like : http://localhost:8080/sampleapp/faces/login.jsp;jsessionid=14EA9092E0D85CAD279BD6D0F6177AF1

I Paste to **IE**
The URL Like : http://localhost:8080/sampleapp/faces/login.jsp

After that I convert my application **JSF1.2 to JSF2.0** Richfaces3.3.3, tomcat6.0.29

Now run my application in **chrome**

My firstpage URL like : http://localhost:8080/sampleapp/login.jsp and
after login my page like http://localhost:8080/sampleapp/faces/content.jsp

Just i copy the url and paste to **FireFox** browser and 
load the first page
URL Like : http://localhost:8080/sampleapp/faces/login.jsp;

This time the **url not changed**. and also **IE** show the same URL.

My config details [JSF1.2 to 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863014/jsf2-0-richfaces-3-3-3-jsp-not-found-error)

**i need to after login,, copy the url,
Then paste to any browser, i need to generate URL like
http://localhost:8080/sampleapp/login.jsp;sessionid=123342342JSDFG1239323SDFKJ1**

how to implement

What happen here...
Help me...
Thanks in advance

Comment: use following link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441713/migrating-from-jsf-1-2-to-jsf-2-0/21227775#21227775

Answer (score 0):

does anything not work?

it seems nothing happend. If you see the jsessionid added to the url the server detected the browser to not support cookies. this may happen even if cookies are enabled. It is some sort of fallback to still allow sessions (by passing the session id via urls).

the application or session handling you have should still work fine.