# Do scope annotations override managed bean scope definitions in faces-config?

Tags: jsf-2, annotations, managed-bean, faces-config

I upgraded an old JSF web application from MyFaces 1.1 to MyFaces 2.2.12, mainly using [Migrating from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441713/migrating-from-jsf-1-2-to-jsf-2-0) as a guide.

Using [Migrating JSF 1.1 with Ajax4jsf 1.x to JSF 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17553033/migrating-jsf-1-1-with-ajax4jsf-1-x-to-jsf-2) as another guide, I also try to replace `a4j:keepAlive` occurences with adding `@ViewScope` annotations to the corresponding beans. Up until now, the beans in our application where managed via the `faces-config.xml` with entries like this:

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>SomeBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>org.some.package.SomeBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

I am also trying to follow advices like [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/rlubke/entry/faces_config_xml_we_don) about replacing as much of the `faces-config.xml` as possible. But when I added the bean and scope annotations like this

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class SomeBean () {
    ...
```

to my bean classes and then ran into an unrelated error in the web application, the MyFaces error debug page showed me that `SomeBean` is still session scoped, not view scoped.

I haven't deleted the corresponding `managed-bean` entry from the `faces-config` file, yet, so I was wondering if settings made in that configuration file override any corresponding annotations in the Java files. Is that the case?

Comment: Lots of these things can be found in the spec, or even in the javadoc. This https://www.google.com/search?q=managed-bean+annotations+override+faces-config provided some insight for me

Comment: And one of the links is even to a SO post... Please improve your searching...